# Python: matching values from one list to the sequence of values in another list

Tags: python, list

Really need help.  I've confused myself with loops and hit a brick wall.

I have two lists.

```
 e_list = [('edward', '1.2.3.4.'), ('jane','1.2.3.4.'), ('jackie', '2.3.4.10.')...]
```

and a_list (the main list to be checked against)

```
 a_list = [('a', '1.2.3.'), ('b', '2.3.'), ('c', '2.3.4.')...]
```

My problem: I want to match the digits in the numbers in *e_list* to the shortest sequence of the numbers in *a_list*.  So that *new_list* is formed to look like:

```
 new_list = [ ('edward', '1.2.3.4', '1.2.3'), ('jane', '1.2.3.4.', '1.2.3'), ('jackie', '2.3.4.10.', '2.3.')...]
```

What I've currently done (not much, I know) is:

```
for e in e_list:
    e_key = e[1]
    for a in a_list:
        a_key = a[1]
        if a_key in e_key:
            print a_key, "in"
```

What this is doing is checking if the numbers of *a_list* are in those of *e_list*.  But then it's printing out "in" for all sequences e.g. jackie is counted as in for both b and c, whereas I want it to be the shortest value, b.  I'm struggling now with what the next step is.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thankyou in advance.

Comment: think you asked the same question on yesterday..

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want match *from the start* of the digit sequence? Since '2.3' also fits with '1.2.3.4'.

Comment: @Evert yes, that is correct.  Matching from the beginning in order.

Comment: Then `a_key in e_key` won't work. You'd need something like `if e_key.startswith(a_key)`. Which won't guarantee that the matched `e_key` is the shortest one; it'll be the first one that fits.

Comment: @Evert surely, if it fits the first one, it's the shortest one?

Comment: No, see Qiang's answer. As long as you don't sort your keys (or list by keys), there's no guarantee that the shortest one will come first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for name, digits in e_list:
    shortest = sorted([d for l, d in a_list if digits.startswith(d)], key=len)[0]
    print name, digits, shortest
```

Comment: Easy.  Simple.  Works.  Thankyou :)

Comment: please see the add on to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829408/python-matching-values-from-one-list-to-the-sequences-of-values-in-another-list

Answer (score 0):

Sort a_list first, and then do the loop to check.

```
a_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
for e in e_list:
    e_key = e[1]
    for a in a_list:
        a_key = a[1]
        if a_key.startswith(e_key):
            print a_key, "in"
            break
```

After the sort, the short digit string in a_list will come first, so in the loop you only need to find the first match.

Comment: I think you may need to replace `a_key in e_key` with `if e_key.startswith(a_key)`, since otherwise '2.3' can be matched with '1.2.3', with is not what the OP wants (see comments below the question).