# Python: matching values from one list to the sequences of values in another list

Tags: python, list

My original question was asked and answered here: [Python: matching values from one list to the sequence of values in another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33754348/python-matching-values-from-one-list-to-the-sequence-of-values-in-another-list)

I have two lists.

```
   e_list = [('edward', '1.2.3.4.'), ('jane','1.2.3.4.'), ('jackie', '2.3.4.10.')...]
```

and a_list (the main list to be checked against)

```
   a_list = [('a', '1.2.3.'), ('b', '2.3.'), ('c', '2.3.4.')...]
```

I'd like a modified output to my original question.  I'm unsure of how I'd change the code snippet to solve the same question but to output all possibilities?

e.g.

```
 new_list = [ ('edward', '1.2.3.4', '1.2.3'), ('jane', '1.2.3.4.', '1.2.3'), ('jackie', '2.3.4.10.', '2.3.'), ('jackie', '2.3.4.10.', '2.3.4')]
```

Comment: Show your input and expected output.

Comment: @ReutSharabani I copied the URL to my previous question so that I don't duplicate my question.  But I'll post it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over everything in `a_list` then deal with the extra case of adding the value in `e_list`. It ends up looking something like this:

```
results = []
for name, x in e_list:
    this_name = [name, x]
    for a, b in a_list:
        if x.startswith(b):
            this_name.append(b)
    results.append(tuple(this_name))

print(results)
```

see this in action here: http://ideone.com/y8uAvC

Comment: thanks for you answer :) is there a way so that jackie becomes two separate tuples in the final list?

Comment: @user47467 that's extremely straightforward, I'm sure you can figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension if you want:

```
res = [(name, digits, match) for name, digits in e_list 
                             for _, match in a_list 
                             if digits.startswith(match)]
print res
```

But since it gets complicated, nested loops may be cleaner. You can use `yield` to get final list:

```
def get_res():
    for name, digits in e_list:
       for _, match in a_list:
           if digits.startswith(match):
              yield name, digits, match

print list(get_res())
```